# method to serialize comment(model) data using parent field to get comment's reply in Django

Tags: django

I have made FoodComment model like this in Django using Foreignkey. It uses username to specify user who owns the comment, and food is for menu which to collect comments of users. And parent points other FoodComment object if it is comment's reply.

```py
class FoodComment(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    star = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.food.menuname + ':' + self.username.username
```

I am having problem with serializer getting jsoned comments data with hierarchy of comments and that of replies.

```py
class FoodCommentList(APIView):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer

    def get(self, request, foodname):
        food = Food.objects.get(menuname=foodname)
        data = FoodComment.objects.select_related('food').filter(food=food, parent=None)

        serialized = CommentSerializer(data, many=True)
        return Response(serialized.data, HTTP_200_OK)
```

If i use views.py's FoodCommentList function as above, REST returns serialized.data as below.

```py
[{"id":1,"body":"delicious!","star":5,"created":"2020-03-26T20:56:49.111307","username":2,"food":19,"parent":null}]
```

And CommentSerializer used above looks like this.

```py
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = FoodComment
        fields = '__all__'
```

What I am trying to do is not just serialize 'parent=None' data but with parent field, I want to get json data with comment's reply like this using serializer.

```
{
   id:1,
   body:"delicious!",
   ...
   childs: {
             id:2,
             body:"ty!",
             ...
   }
]
```

I have tried code by other users but couldn't solve it. Is it possible to call CommentSerializer once and get comment's reply in recursive way using serializer?

Thank You!